# Java Application Auto Update

Tags: java

We have an java application hello.jar and a server where the application updates resides. We have implemented an mechanism in the application hellow.jar which downloads the latest jar in the updates folder.

so

I run the hello.jar

hello.jar downloads the updates.zip inside updates

Then hello.jar extracts the updates.zip file and extracts the
    updater.jar and latest hello.jar

Next using process builder it launch the update.jar and hello.jar
    exists itself using system.exit(0)

Now updater.jar copies the original hello.jar to backup

Then updater.jar copies the latest application from update/hello.jar
    to current directory

Then updater.jar removes the /backup directory

Next update .jar deletes the /updates directory

Finally updater.jar launches the hello.jar again and exits itself

Please let me know if there is any better alternative approach.

Answer (score -2):

This is almost exact the same way I resolved it. Because my "update.jar" will not be changed in any way, I don`t download it again.

Comment: is it safe to call system.exit(0) just after firing the processbuilder to launch an executable? Is there any possibility that the parent application exits before the processbuilder able to launch the jar file

Comment: if you are unsure, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication , there are some ways to communicate between two JVM`s, so maybe you can check if your updater.jar is started correctly before calling System.exit(0).